# How to add third-party scripts in a Chrome Extension that runs inside Gmail to develop a @mentions feature

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a @mentions feature in my Chrome Extension, using jquery atwho (https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/516/how-to-create-a-mentions-autocomplete-with-jquery-and-atwho). This Extension runs changing Gmail Interface. I have comment box inside a popup, which I want to have the atwho feature. What is the correct way to insert these scripts in my code? (Should I push the script in the header of Gmail, or is there some other way?). (Usually all the other third-parties scripts I use, are in a vendor.js file and are not pushed in the header of the page).

Initially, trying to insert the script in the header, I get an error that jQuery is undefined. After I also insert the script in the header of Gmail, my Extension does not load correct.

Comment: There's no code here... have you tried using a packing tool like Browserify to pack your code before putting it into the extension?

Comment: To access the web page you need to use a *content script*, see the documentation.